# empty input javascript says unanswered ? can anybody?

Tags: javascript, html, input

im working on a javascript code and so far got it to be almost completed, the idea is fill gaps exercises ; and so far i got it answers with this code

```
         if (A0.toLowerCase()=="whatever")
             {
          Answers.document.write("<p>Question 1 - Correct.</p>");
           }
          else
          {
          Answers.document.write("<p>Question 1 - Incorrect. Actual Answer was: whatever.                 </p>");
          }

          A0=document.forms[0].box0.value;
```

and this is the form

```
           <form name="form1" ONSUBMIT="MarkAnswers()">

           <P>1. How <input type="text" name="box0" size="10"> test tes test</P>

           >
```

my question is , what code i'd add so i can get the answer of unansnwered question intread of correct or incorrect when the input field left empty and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
 if (A0.toLowerCase()=="whatever")
     {
  Answers.document.write("<p>Question 1 - Correct.</p>");
   }
  elseif(A0 == "")
  {
  //do something
  }
  else
  {
  Answers.document.write("<p>Question 1 - Incorrect. Actual Answer was: whatever.                 </p>");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are wanting to check if `A0` is empty. Just add another comparison to your `if` statement. I'd also trim the content in case they just have a space character, for example:

```
var answer = A0.toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g); // Lowercase, then trim leading/trailing WS
if (!answer) {
    Answers.document.write("<p>Question 1 - Unanswered.</p>");
} else if (answer == "whatever") {
    Answers.document.write("<p>Question 1 - Correct.</p>");
} else {
    Answers.document.write("<p>Question 1 - Incorrect. Actual Answer was: whatever.                 </p>");
}
```